# unable to uncheck checkbox after using java script

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function enableDisable(textBoxID,checkboxID) {
        if(document.getElementById(checkboxID).checked= true) {
            document.getElementById(textBoxID).style.display = 'block';
            return true;
        } else {
            document.getElementById(textBoxID).style.display = 'none';
            return true;
        }   
    }
</script>

legacy<input type="checkbox" class="igm_class" id="legacy_cb" name="igm_2" value="legacy" onchange="enableDisable('legacytb','legacy_cb')">
```

This code is working fine. when the checkbox is checked then the text box is displayed but I am unable to uncheck the checkbox.. The check box remains checked

Comment: please reformate your code,

Comment: @Ranjith Please follow the guidelines for posting question on SO. Also search on SO for similar question I am sure you find your answer.

Comment: If condition should be `document.getElementById(checkboxID).checked == true`. `=` is used for assignment, `==` and `===` is used for comparison

Comment: Thanks . The code is now working fine

Answer (score 4):

Because you use a single equation in the if condition. In js it's generally a good idea to use triple equation when checking value:

```
if(document.getElementById(checkboxID).checked === true) {
```

Or even better just leave the equations like this:

```
if(document.getElementById(checkboxID).checked) {
```

Answer (score -1):

replace "if(document.getElementById(checkboxID).checked = true)" with "if(document.getElementById(checkboxID).checked === true)"

```html
function enableDisable(textBoxID, checkboxID) {
    if (document.getElementById(checkboxID).checked === true) {
        document.getElementById(textBoxID).style.display = 'block';
        return true;
    }

    else {
        document.getElementById(textBoxID).style.display = 'none';
        return true;
    }
}
```